# Grep ambiguity nested square bracket

Tags: regex, grep

`sample.txt` contains

```
abcde
abde
```

Can anybody explain the output of following commands -

1. `grep '[[ab]]' sample.txt`    - no output
2. `grep '[ab[]]' sample.txt`    - no output
3. `grep '[ab[]' sample.txt`     - output is `abcde` , `abde`
4. `grep '[ab]]' sample.txt`     - no output

And what does `[(ab)]` and `[^(ab)]` mean? Is it the same as `[ab]` and `[^ab]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to understand is, inside a character class, none of the meta-characters of regex has any special meaning. They are matched literally. For e.g., an `*` will match a `*` and will not mean `0 or 1` repetition. Similarly, `()` will match `(` and `)`, and will not create a `capture group`.

Now, if a `]` is found in a character class, that automatically closes the character class, and the further character won't be the part of that character class. Now, let's understand what is happening above:

---

In `1`, `2`, and `4`, your character class ends at the first closing `]`. So, the last closing bracket - `]`, is not the part of character class. It has to be matched separately. So, your pattern will match something like this:

```
'[[ab]]' is same as '([|a|b)(])'  // The last `]` has to match.
'[ab[]]' is same as '(a|b|[)(])'  // Again, the last `]` has to match.
'[ab]]'  is same as '(a|b|])(])'  // Same, the last `]` has to match.
    ^
    ^---- Character class closes here.
```

Now, since in both the string, there is no `]` at the end, hence no match is found.

Whereas, in the 3rd pattern, your character class is closed only by the last `]`. And hence everything comes inside the character class.

```
'[ab[]' means match string that contains 'a', or 'b', or '['
```

which is perfectly valid and match both the string.

---

> And what does `[(ab)]` and `[^(ab)]` mean?

`[(ab)]` means match any of the `(`, `a`, `b`, `)`. Remember, inside a character class, no meta-character of regex has any special meaning. So, you can't create groups inside a character class.

`[^(ab)]` means exact opposite of `[(ab)]`. It matches any string which does not contain any of those characters specified.

---

> Is it the same as `[ab]` and `[^ab]` ?

No. These two does not include `(` and `)`. Hence they are little different.

Answer (score 2):

I give it a try:

```
grep '[[ab]]' - match string  which has one of "[,a,b" and then a "]" char followed
grep '[ab[]]' - match string  which has one of "a,b,[" and then a "]" char followed
grep '[ab[]'  - match string  which has one of "a,b,["
grep '[ab]]'  - match string  which has one of "a,b" and then a "]" char followed
grep '[(ab)]' - match string  which has one of "(,a,b,)"
grep '[^(ab)]' - match string  which doesn't contain "(,a,b" and ")"
grep '[ab]'    - match string  which contains one of "a,b"
grep '[^ab]' - match string  which doesn't contain "a" and "b"
```

you can go through those `grep` cmds on this example:

```
#create a file with below lines:
abcde
abde
[abcd
abcd]
abc[]foo
abc]bar
[ab]cdef
a(b)cde
```

you will see the difference, and think about it with my comment/explanation.